# PHP Soap server slow on different computers

Tags: php, soap

Any reason why a soap server can be slow on different computers and networks? For me its working very good but for other people in different networks is very slow, like minutes.

Any reason for that?

Thanks

Comment: I think this question should be asked on http://serverfault.com/ and with more details (server spec, os and ect.)... However you should figure out which exactly action takes more time to be completed on different enviroment

Comment: hmm ... this cannot be a php soap configuration problem?

Comment: You're going to have to post a lot more information than that for anyone to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use the SOAP stuff much with PHP, so the only PHP configuration thing I can think of is caching:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 1);
```

Or see the parameters to:

```
SoapClient::SoapClient($wsdl, $options)
SoapServer::SoapServer($wsdl, $options)
```

Otherwise it's likely to be networking issues or configuration outside the realm of PHP and a stackoverflow question.